# Parsing data in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data in a single column.

| Test Name |
| --- |
| Age:40 |
| City, Division |
| University Name |
| Subject Name |
| Match Percentage 75% |
| Phone Number" |

I need to split this data and insert it into different columns like by using SQL-

```
NAME  AGE  CITY  NAME_OF_UNI NAME_OF_SUB MATCH_PCT  PHONE_NUM
```

Comment: Sample data looks fabricated. Can't you provide something that at least looks like real data? Also, which rules should be applied to distinguish one column from another? What are separators? What if "names" consist of more than a single word?

Comment: Real data looks like this -
    
    SL      COL1
    1       Test Name1   Age: 30     CITY1     NAME_OF_UNI1     NAME_OF_SUB1
    2       Test Name2   Age: 35     CITY2     NAME_OF_UNI2     NAME_OF_SUB2
    
    My requirement is now substring this COL1 value and insert it like below by SQL query (db version 11g)-
    
    SL      COL1            COL2        COL3     COL4                     COL5 
    1       Test Name1   Age: 30     CITY1     NAME_OF_UNI1     NAME_OF_SUB1
    2       Test Name2   Age: 35     CITY2     NAME_OF_UNI2     NAME_OF_SUB2
    
    Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the sample data and format it as a table so that it’s readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind of difficult (at least, for me) to understand how sample data really looks like; there's a colon (as name-value separator), there's nothing, there are double quotes. So, I adjusted it a little bit and used colon *everywhere*.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Age:40
City:
University Name:
Subject Name:
Match Percentage: 75%
Phone Number:

Age:12
City: Zagreb
University Name: FER
Subject Name: Maths
Match Percentage: 23%
Phone Number: 003851123456
```

Query: first split each column value into separate rows, and then apply a simple case expression which searches for *anything* that follows colon character.

```
SQL> with tsplit as
  2    (select rowid rid,
  3       column_value lvl,
  4       trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^' || chr(10) ||']+', 1, column_value)) val
  5     from test cross join
  6       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  7                           connect by level <= 6
  8                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  9    )
 10  select
 11    max(case when lvl = 1 then substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1) end) age,
 12    max(case when lvl = 2 then substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1) end) city,
 13    max(case when lvl = 3 then substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1) end) university,
 14    max(case when lvl = 4 then substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1) end) subject,
 15    max(case when lvl = 5 then substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1) end) match,
 16    max(case when lvl = 6 then substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 1) end) phone
 17  from tsplit
 18  group by rid;

AGE CITY       UNIVERSITY   SUBJECT    MATCH      PHONE
--- ---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- --------------
40                                      75%
12   Zagreb     FER          Maths      23%        003851123456

SQL>
```

If my assumption is wrong, then adjust query so that you don't search for a colon, but each "name" string separately. But, as far as the general idea is concerned, this might be one option.